# Proving $f(A)\leq Z(H)$

Tags: group-theory

Please help me to prove that if $f: G\to H$ is surjection and $A\leq Z(G)$ then $f(A)\leq Z(H)$. Thank you.

Comment: $[f(A),H]=[f(A),f(G)]=f([A,G])\le f([Z(G),G])=f(1)=1$ is how I'd do it, but this is perhaps not instructive without further elaboration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably $f : G \to H$ is assumed to be a surjective group homomorphism.

We have to show $f(a) h = h f(a)$ for $a \in A$. Well, choose some $g \in G$ with $h = f(g)$. Then $f(a) h = f(a) f(g) = f(a g)= \dotsc$ I think you should be able to solve this.